# IO Exception - File being used by another process (Can't open file following directory creation)

Tags: c#, ios, directory

I have got a project on the go that monitors patients for a vet while they are being operated on and writes the result to a text file. While I was experimenting with the outputting I just let the files save in the Debug folder, which worked fine. However, I've now created a full directory that creates or opens a main folder, and then a sub folder (based on input text from the program), to save the text file into.

```
    private void createDirectory()
    { //create output file in this folder using owner name and current date

        //main folder path (contains all files output from system)
        string rootDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Horse Monitoring Records";
        //sub folder path (each patient has individual subfolder)
        string subDirectory = rootDirectory + "\\" + txtPatName.Text + "-" + txtOwnerName.Text;
        //file name (patient has file created for each operation)
        fileName = subDirectory +  "\\" + txtOwnerName.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".txt";

        if (!Directory.Exists(rootDirectory)) //if main folder does not exist...
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(rootDirectory); //create it in My Documents
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(subDirectory)) //if patient sub folder does not exist...
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectory); //create it in Patient-Owner format
        }
        if (!File.Exists(fileName)) //if monitoring file does not exist...
        {
            File.Create(fileName); //create it in Owner-Date format
        }
    }
```

This stage works fine, but as soon as you try to save some data to the text file, it throws to a run time error stating that

> The file cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process.

The exception is brought up here:

```
    private void saveFileDetails()
    {
        //Once case details have been entered, create new file using these details and add data input structure
        StreamWriter consoleFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    ...
    }
```

When I went and checked out the folder, the relevant sub-folder and file had been created but the text file was blank.
I'm guessing it's something to do with closing the text file after creating the directory, which means it's already open when the system tries to open it. I can't figure out how to sort this issue out though!

The two functions shown above are called like this:

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        //file details entered upon load written to new file - according to PatID
        createDirectory();
        saveFileDetails();
    }
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: If you write immediately after `File.Create(fileName)`, it's possible that the operating system hasn't released the file yet. Instead of checking whether the file exists, you can use the overloads of `StreamWriter` which take FileXXXX enums as parameters.

Comment: My bad, you need to use FileStream and pass that to the StreamWrifer.

Comment: You don't need to pass a FileStream to StreamWriter. There is an overload of the constructor where you pass a file path and if the file exists it opens the file and if not, it creates the file. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Ah, indeed there is! [`StreamWriter(string, bool)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you do

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName)) //if monitoring file does not exist...
{
    File.Create(fileName); //create it in Owner-Date format
}
```

Right before you try to write to the file. Because you've just created it (if it didn't exist), chances are that the operating system hasn't released the file yet.

Like @Jauch mentioned in the comments, you could skip this check completely and use the `StreamWriter` overload which will create file if it doesn't exist, or append to it if it does.

```
private void saveFileDetails()
{
    //Once case details have been entered, create new file using these details and add data input structure
    using (StreamWriter consoleFile = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use the following to write all of your text at once:

```
File.AppendAllText(textToWrite, fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

`File.Create(fileName)` returns an open stream to the file which is never closed.

To create an empty file use `File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, new byte[0]);`

Otherwise the 2 methods can be shortend

```
private void SaveFileDetails()
{
    string subDirectory = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
        "Horse Monitoring Records");

    // create the folder hierarchy if not exists. does nothing if already there
    Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectory);

    // each patient has individual file
    var filepath = Path.Combine(subDirectory,
        txtPatName.Text + "-" + txtOwnerName.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt");

    // creates the file if not exists
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, append: true, encoding: Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        // write details
    }
}
```

Note:

- merged 2 methods
- .NET naming conventions applied
- changed dateformat to better sort by name in explorer

Answer (score 0):

`StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable`, so wrapping it in a using block can manage closing and disposing the writer and ensuring it is available the next time you want to touch that file.  It can also manage creating the text file if it doesn't exist, removing the need to explicitly call `File.Create`.

```
StreamWriter consoleFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
```

becomes

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
{
    // writing, etc.
}
```

or

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
{ // true says "append to file if it exists, create if it doesn't"
    // writing, etc.
}
```

Whatever seems more readable to you will work fine.